# Ajax error function not calling in java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

**Ajax error function not calling in java**

Here is the ajax method:-

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    timeout:5000,
    url:"<s:property value="URL"/>",
    data:{name:newName},
    success:function () {
        $("#errorDiv").html("Successfully updated");
    },
    error:function (data) {
        $("#errorDiv").html("Error.");
    }
})
```

Update User method:-

```
    @Action(value = "renameUser", results = {@Result(name = "success", type = "json"),
    @Result(name = "input", type = "tiles", location = "view.list")},
            interceptorRefs = {@InterceptorRef("auditingAdminDefault")})
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        String result = "input";
        try {
            updateUser(name);
            addActionMessage(name + " user name was successfully updated.");
            result = "success";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            addActionMessage(e.getMessage());
            result = "input";
        }
        return result;
    }
}

updateUser();

updateUser() throws Exception {

if (..) {

} else {
  throw Exception();
}
```

**I am able to update user successfully without issues. But success function is called for successful update or any error thrown.**

**There are two things I need to use in Ajax.**

- Success and error method should be called based on result
- I need to catch the error from update user method and show it in UI.

**Kindly anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?**

Comment: Are you sure the request is even being made? What event are you running it under? Have you checked that event fires? What's the value of `newName`? What's the response (if any) in the network tab of the console?

Comment: when success, I get data as Object { name: "test1" } and when error, I get as follows "
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>....."

Comment: Its returning whole normal HTML page not 404.

Answer (score 1):

you are catching all the errors in your action method and returning a valid response to the client .

```
catch (Exception e) {
        addActionMessage(e.getMessage());
        result = "input";
    }

return result;
```

This is why even in case of failure, the success call back is called since for client side the response is a valid one. you should return an error in the action method in case some exception occurs.

Ideally you should return an Error View for any exception.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
   addActionMessage(e.getMessage());
   return View("Error");
}
```

but in your case you want to display the error in the same view hence you can do something like that

you can do something like this for exception.

```
public ActionResult execute() throws Exception {
{
    try
    {
        //code everything works fine
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will remove the try and catch block. How to catch exception thrown from updateUser method and show in UI. Example Error: "Error in Updating user". Refer my updateUser method in question.

Comment: What is the View mean. Is it custom method or need to import ?

Comment: Error view is used to hide the exception details from the end user but since you want to do handling in the ajax call back i have edited the answer. In case of some error a 500 (server error) http code will be return to the client and the error call back will be fired.

Comment: @karan did it help ?

Comment: No. I am not able to use ActionResult and HttpStatusCodeResult. Do i need to add separate dependency for it? I am using return type as String. Do you want me to use ActionResult ?

Comment: yes, if you want to use an error call back then return type string will not  be sufficient.

Comment: If I want to call success and error based on try catch block without error callback. How to do it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128169/discussion-between-karan-and-deep).

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the following issues:-

1. Ajax Error callback not called when error occurs
2. Catch exception from method and show in ajax function

Following is the updated method and its working now:-

Update User method:-

```
private String errorStatement;

public String getErrorStatement() {
    return errorStatement;
}

@Action(value = "renameUser", results = {@Result(name = "success", type = "json"),
@Result(name = "input", type = "json", , params = { "statusCode", "500" })},
        interceptorRefs = {@InterceptorRef("auditingAdminDefault")})
@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {

    try {
        updateUser(name);

        return SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        errorStatement = e.getMessage();
        return ERROR;
    }

}
```

}